# No match for operator== when trying to find an element in vector of class

Tags: c++, header-files, stdvector

I am making a Book Manager and I want to implement a function where I can search an author and it will print all the books that he's made.

Here is the main code for the finding function:

```cpp
void Library::FindByAuthor(void) {
    char author[100];
    cout << "Specify authors name: ";
    cin >> noskipws >> author;

    place = find(bookArray.begin(), bookArray.end(), author);

    if (place != bookArray.end()) {
        cout << "Found author " << "(" << author << ")" << "and he has a book called "
        << bookArray[place - bookArray.begin()].getBookName();
}
```

The `Library` header file contains the vector of bookArray:

```cpp
vector<Book> bookArray;
vector<Book>::iterator place; // It also contains an iterator
```

I've also tried using `std::find_if()` but that didn't work.

The error says:

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h|241|error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Book' and 'const char [100]')|
```

The format of the .txt file comes like this:

```
BookName  AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName  Genre1  Genre2  Description  Date
```

I have a `vector<Book>` (where the `Book` is a class in `Book.h`) and it stores all books from the `.txt` file.

This is the code for storing data from `.txt` to the vector:

```cpp
void Library::LoadBooks(void) {
    Book book;
    string str;
    ifstream file("Book.txt");
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Couldn't load book.txt!" << "\nExiting!";
        abort();
    }

    while(getline(file, str)) {
        size_t i = str.find("  ");
        book.setBookName(str.substr(0, i));
        str = str.substr(i + 1);

        i = str.find("  ");
        book.setAuthorName(str.substr(0, i));
        str = str.substr(i + 1);

        i = str.find("  ");
        book.setKnjRod(str.substr(0, i));
        str = str.substr(i + 1);

        i = str.find("  ");
        book.setKnjVrsta(str.substr(0, i));
        str = str.substr(i + 1);

        i = str.find("  ");
        book.setDescription(str.substr(0, i));
        str = str.substr(i + 1);

        i = str.find("  ");
        book.setDate(str.substr(i + 1));

        bookArray.push_back(book);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: The error looks pretty straightforward. The program doesn't know how to compare a `Book` from your vector and the `char []` author for equality. Have you tried adding an `operator==()` to your `Book` for `char []` like the error suggests? What confuses you about this error?

Comment: Is there a reason why `FindByAuthor()` us using `char[]` instead of `std::string`?  Also, in `LoadBooks()`, you can simplify the parsing of the `while` loop by using a `std::istringstream` instead of `find()`+`substr()`.

Comment: I was trying to keep the white spaces and I was looking through forums and found a way to put char var[100] so that it can handle the white spaces.

This didn't came out to be true and I found the noskipws. I then tried to replace it with string but that didn't work for some reason. I am practicing for my first programming competition and I thought it would be great to make a book manager for my mother since she has lots of books.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no comparison operator between `struct Book` and `char[]`, you can use `std::find_if` like:

```cpp
place = std::find_if(
    bookArray.begin(), bookArray.end(),
    [author](Book const& book) {
        return !strcmp(author, book.getAuthorName().c_str());
    }
);
```

but I would rather use `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: It says that it fails to pass Book as 'this'. Although thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that there is no `operator==` defined that can compare a `Book` object to a `char[]` array.  You are using `std::find()` to search a vector of `Book` objects for a specific `Book` that compares equal to `author`.  But you have not defined such a comparison, eg:

```cpp
class Book {
    ...
public:
    ...
    bool operator==(const string &author) {
        return getAuthorName() == author;
    }
};
```

Otherwise, use `std::find_if()` instead, eg:

```cpp
void Library::FindByAuthor() {
    string author;
    cout << "Specify authors name: ";
    std::getline(cin, author);

    vector<Book>::iterator place = find_if(bookArray.begin(), bookArray.end(),
        [&](const Book &b){ return b.getAuthorName() == author; }
    );

    if (place != bookArray.end()) {
        cout << "Found author (" << author << ") and he has a book called " << place->getBookName();
    }
}
```

---

On a side note, `LoadBooks()` can be simplified a bit by using `std::istringstream`, eg:

```cpp
void Library::LoadBooks()
{
    ifstream file("Book.txt");
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Couldn't load book.txt!" << "\nExiting!";
        abort();
    }

    string str;
    while (getline(file, str)) {
        istringstream iss(str);
        Book book;

        iss >> str;
        book.setBookName(str);

        iss >> str;
        book.setAuthorName(str);

        iss >> str;
        book.setKnjRod(str);

        iss >> str;
        book.setKnjVrsta(str);

        iss >> str;
        book.setDescription(str);

        iss >> str;
        book.setDate(str);

        bookArray.push_back(book);
    }
}
```

Or, if you need to handle strings that have spaces inside of them, I would suggest separating the strings with tabs and then using `std::getline()` with `'\t'` as the line delimiter, eg:

```cpp
void Library::LoadBooks()
{
    ifstream file("Book.txt");
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Couldn't load book.txt!" << "\nExiting!";
        abort();
    }

    string str;
    while (getline(file, str)) {
        istringstream iss(str);
        Book book;

        getline(iss, str, '\t');
        book.setBookName(str);

        getline(iss, str, '\t');
        book.setAuthorName(str);

        getline(iss, str, '\t');
        book.setKnjRod(str);

        getline(iss, str, '\t');
        book.setKnjVrsta(str);

        getline(iss, str, '\t');
        book.setDescription(str);

        getline(iss, str, '\t');
        book.setDate(str);

        bookArray.push_back(book);
    }
}
```

Either way, consider implementing an `operator>>` for `Book` instead, that will simplify `LoadBooks()` even further, eg:

```cpp
class Book {
    ...
public:
    ...
    friend istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Book &book) {
        string str;
        if (getline(in, str)) {
            // parse str into book as needed...
        }
        return in;
    }
};

void Library::LoadBooks()
{
    ifstream file("Book.txt");
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Couldn't load book.txt!" << "\nExiting!";
        abort();
    }

    Book book;
    while (file >> book) {
        bookArray.push_back(book);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me!

I ran into a problem where it couldn't parse Book as 'this' argument. I will take a deeper look why. Thanks for your efforts!